# Improve Query Performance when huge amount of data in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like to know is there any method to increase the performance when i got 995498 data inside the table. Every time when i just select * from table it took me almost 20-30 second to load it out.

Comment: Yes you can select only required columns. Add indexing on the key columns.

Comment: And you are using both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: Buy a solid state disk? Seriously for this type of "data dump" query you are limited by the transfer rate from disk to memory.

Comment: Now i usually doing like select top 100 * from table order by ID desc .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

1. Don't use Select * without constraints;

   1. Limit the amount of rows you want to retrieve (bundle your requests by 10000 rows for instance);
   2. Limit the number of columns you want to retrieve;
2. Add indexing on the key columns.
3. Buy an SSD.

Comment: Okay, thanks your concern , i was doing like 
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [Table] Order by [ID] desc

Comment: If you do SELECT TOP 100 you should not get 995498 data as you state in your post.

Comment: Ya, i mean i using this way to get a part of the query , just wondering if there any method to select all from table with faster performance.

Comment: Those have been listed in my answer. Please mark it as correct if there's no better alternative answer.